# Count and Show Compile Error

Tags: macros, errors

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\ad#1{$^{#1}$}
\def\aff#1{$^{#1}$}
\def\address#1{#1}
\def\dept#1{#1}
\def\inst#1{#1}
\def\cyname#1{#1}
\def\country#1{#1}
\def\pcode#1{#1}
\def\stname#1{#1}
\def\phone#1{#1}
\def\fax#1{#1}
\def\ad#1{$^{\rm #1}$}
\def\aff#1{$^{#1}$}
\def\fn#1{#1}
\def\sn#1{#1}
\def\corr#1{#1}
\def\statename#1{#1}


\begin{document}

\title{Sample}

\author{Sas Santhome\ad{a} Author\ad{b} and Susanna Waxxarin\ad{c} }

\maketitle

\address{\aff{a}\dept{Department of Sciences}, \inst{University}, \cyname{City}, \country{Italy}; \aff{b}\dept{Department of Economics}, \inst{University}, \cyname{Trieste}, \country{Italy}}

\end{document}
```

what i want to acheive is in `\author` i have `\ad{}` 'n' number of times,

the link text `\ad{a}` should also be there in `\aff{a}` or else, i need to show compile error,

for example in the above coding, we can see

```
\ad{a} - \aff{a}
\ad{b} - \aff{b}
\ad{c} - Missing \aff{c}
```

\aff{c} is missing but \ad{c} is present, so i should throw compile error

Please guide

Answer (score 1):

For example you can save the `\ad` labels into the `\afflist` macro and you can use these labels from `\afflist` when `\aff` is used. This means that you needn't to repeat the labels again and the `\aff` macro is used without parameter.

```
\def\addto#1#2{\expandafter\def\expandafter#1\expandafter{#1#2}}
\def\ad#1{$^{\rm #1}$\global\addto\afflist{{#1}}}
\def\aff{%
   \ifx\afflist\empty \errmessage{There is more \noexpand\aff than \string\ad}%
   \else \expandafter\affA\afflist\end $^{\rm\tmp}$%
   \fi
}
\def\affA#1#2\end{\gdef\afflist{#2}\def\tmp{#1}}
\def\address#1{#1%
  \ifx\afflist\empty\else \errmessage{There is more \noexpand\ad than \string\aff}\fi
}
\def\afflist{}    

\def\dept#1{#1}   
\def\inst#1{#1}   
\def\cyname#1{#1} 
\def\country#1{#1}
\def\pcode#1{#1} 
\def\stname#1{#1}
\def\phone#1{#1}
\def\fax#1{#1} 
\def\fn#1{#1}  
\def\sn#1{#1}  
\def\corr#1{#1}
\def\statename#1{#1}

...

\address{\aff\dept{Department of Sciences}, \inst{University}, \cyname{City}, \country{Italy}; 
         \aff\dept{Department of Economics}, \inst{University}, \cyname{Trieste}, \country{Italy}; 
         \aff\dept{Somewhere}}
```

If you need to repeat the labels in the `\aff` macro again then you can check if the label is the same:

```
\def\aff#1{\def\tmpa{#1}%
   \ifx\afflist\empty \errmessage{There is more \noexpand\aff than \string\ad}%
   \else \expandafter\affA\afflist\end $^{\rm\tmp}$%
         \ifx\tmp\tmpa \else \errmessage{unmatched labels \tmpa--\tmp}\fi
   \fi
}
```